# Python IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am just trying to open an image, I know there are several IOError questions on here, but I have not been able to understand the explanations.

The code i typed is here

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("Lenna.png")
image.load()
```

The error obtained is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\hello world.py", line 4, in <module>
    image = Image.open("Lenna.png")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Lenna.png'
```

What do I do here?
Thank you.

Comment: Read the error; there is no such file named 'Lenna.png' found

Comment: What is so confusing about `No such file or directory: 'Lenna.png'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use relative filename. Python can't find such file in current work dir. Try to use full absolute path such as 'C:\Lenna.png'.

Answer (score 0):

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Lenna.png'

check  path of the file

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open image, either you have to specify the complete path of the image like,

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('C:/Users/Anish/Desktop/2017PROJECTS/PYTHON_TWITTER/image/camel.png')
im.show()
```

Or you have to copy the image to the specified project directory and call  the image name like,

```
im = Image.open('camel.png')
```